# Как импортировать .db файл в таблицу mySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

У меня есть .db файл и таблица mySQL. Как перевести .db файл в .sql или сразу же импортировать его в таблицу?
Все коды желательно писать на языке Python.

Comment: Когда вы гуглить уж начнёте. https://anyconv.com/ru/konverter-db-v-sql/

Comment: Если хочешь всё своими руками то: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823164/how-to-convert-db-file-to-sql-file

Comment: *У меня есть .db файл* Отлично. А что в этом файле-то? надеюсь, это не Парадоксовская таблица?